# Country tag "entering new country" in OSRM or other services

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

In the route ResultSet from OSRM there is no information about the current country the route goes through.

Is there a way to get the information by entering a new country in openstreetmap?

I have checked OSRM, but this information is not available.

I am searching for a routing service based on OpenstreetMap, that provides this information.

Comment: Should be possible with a customized GraphHopper http://stackoverflow.com/a/35694881/194609

Comment: thanks. but GraphHopper is not free, am searching for a free solution. It's possible to customized ORSM to do that ?

Comment: The GraphHopper routing engine is not only free it is even open source: https://graphhopper.com/#community